# Retrieving an image url after upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to use a basic upload form to place an image onto my server, and would like the code to post the new image url on the page after the upload. I am aware this is a vague question, but I have done a good amount of searching with no usable results. If anyone could help me with this or just give a point in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"> <br />
<button>Upload File</button>
<p>
</form>
```

is all that I have so far I know it is not much to start with I do not know how to handle the data that is sent to 'upload.php'

Comment: so whats the deal? tell me what you have done so far?

Comment: Post the code of what you have done, so that any additions can be suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). Similar to how you use the `$_POST` array, you can use the `$_FILES` array to retrieve files that were submitted by a form.

The `$_FILES` array will contain `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` after upload, where "file" is the input name in the form. There are PHP frameworks that help you work better with the temporary files though.

How to use? In the php file containing the form:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then in upload_file.php:

```
echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
```

Is this what you were asking for ?

Comment: yes that is perfect. Now I did notice that it created a temp file how may I get around to making it a permanent upload?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that last question I did not see the link in your answer.

Comment: No Problem, glad it helped! Normally you copy the file to a folder of your choice by using move_uploaded_file() or some other functions depending on what framework you're using.

Comment: I got it working how I imagined just had to do a bit of editing from the w3 tutorial if I could upvote I would but anyways thanks again man I really appreciate the help

Comment: My pleasure man, good luck with your project! And also remember, if you wanna make it public consider using something like Yii or Codeigniter or other php frameworks, they make things much cooler ;)